# a display 20% of query results to a Specific Column

Tags: sql-server

Hello I am newbie (from France - Wines !) in database administration : and I want to display a report containing 20% result for each service: I will put this code below but 
it gives me nothing:n:

```
ALTER procedure test
as

BEGIN

Set NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @CodePrestation nvarchar(50);
set @CodePrestation='select distinct code_prestation FROM vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth where code_prestation=613229'
WHILE (@CodePrestation<>'NULL')
BEGIN
   set @Query='select TOP(20)percent[code_prestation],[Libellé Prestation] FROM vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth where [code_prestation]='+@CodePrestation;
END
end 
set @Query=@Query
execute sp_executesql @Query
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: First of all, you should ask your question in english, or at least try to make it so we can understand you. And in the second place, that query doesn't make sense at all

Comment: `distinct code_prestation FROM vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth where code_prestation=613229` will be `613229` or an empty result. I can't really guess what you are even trying to do here.

Comment: @Lamak - Its not too hard. I can speak french too. Watch me. What struck me is the `urgent` word. I don't need any translator to repond to that.

Comment: hello; I am newbie in database administration: and I want to display the 20% for each service type, that is to say if I have a delivery 'remourquage' I must show 20% of cases for this LAST

Comment: @user3701046 - use `google translate`. French to English. Cheers from US & A. Chenqui.

Comment: Can you show a few rows of example data and desired results for that data?

Comment: @user3701046 - look at all these dodo's talking in English. Let me teach them - S'il vous plaît montrer quelques tables et les lignes échantillon. Afficher également les résultats attendus et les erreurs, le cas échéant.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Vous pouvez parler en français si vous croyez en vous-même - Go figure.

Comment: j'ai pas encore de données a affiché mais dans la base de donnée j'ai 2 tables (prestation,dossier)ce que je veux c'est d'afficher pour chaque prestation le 20 % du résultat qui peux être afficher  pour chacune de cette derniere

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev over to you!

Comment: @user3701046 - frère, vous devez montrer la sortie désirée. Btw, je ne parle pas français. J'utilise un traducteur - https://translate.google.com/

Comment: I have no data yet posted but in the database I have 2 tables (service, file) that I want is to display for each service, 20% of the results can be displayed for each the latter

Answer (score 1):

Try someting like this:

```
DECLARE @Percent  int
SET @Percent = (SELECT COUNT(*)*0.2 FROM #Test)

SELECT Top (@Percent) * FROM #Test
```

I hope this will give you what you want.

Have a nice day 
Etienne

**Update**

There is a much easier way:

```
SELECT TOP(20) PERCENT * From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script, it will give the first 20 % of each CodePrestation rounded up:

```
DECLARE @vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth  table
(
  [code_prestation] int,
  [Libellé Prestation] int
)
INSERT @vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth
values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(1,2)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    ntile(5) over (PARTITION BY [code_prestation] ORDER BY [Libellé Prestation]) n,
    [code_prestation],
    [Libellé Prestation] 
  FROM @vw_Details_Requete_Qualite_oth 
)
SELECT 
  [code_prestation],
  [Libellé Prestation]
FROM CTE
WHERE n = 1
```

Result:

```
code_prestation Libellé Prestation
1               1
1               2
2               1
```

This is not written for your table, it is written as an example. It should be easy to convert to your environment. though.